# Mercurial continuous integration

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration

I have a mercurial workflow question. If let's say a group of developers are developing different features in parallel on different branches and they want to mark the 'stable' point on their branch so it can be integrated into the next build, what is the best way forward?

In the good old days of CVS, we'd use tags for this purpose but they don't work that way for hg. So instead, should we be maintaining multiple repos like development and release_candidate, then developers push their stable branches to rc and the auto build system monitors this repo to trigger a build?

If the stable point on the development branch is not the newest changeset on that branch, the developer should remember to specify up to which changeset he will be pushing, right?

So, does this sound like an efficient workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not one solution to the issue, but it depends on personal preferences.

For one, and my recommended way: mercurial knows different phases. Thus it's possible to use them for the means you indicate: Use a central repository which is indicated as non-publishing, thus draft phase will be retained. Then developers can pull and push normally. Those changesets which they deem stable are given explicitly 'public' phase by them, the unstable ones remain in phase 'draft'. Alternatively they keep them in phase 'secret' exclusively on their own machine, thus they are not pushed to the central server at all.
See http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/88203 and [Phases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases) for details.

Of course they could also only and explicitly push the changesets which they want to see published - but that's a method which is bound to fail much much earlier. Similarily, it's easier to do a mistake when pulling and pushing to different 'release' and 'development' repositories.

However I see no reason why tagging would not work for you - but maybe bookmarks are closer to what you know from CVS. Thus you could also use bookmarks in a similar way.

Further, independent of anything above and if there's no special release manager or so: if you trust your developers to merge their changes themselves into the release branch, then there's no reason they couldn't merge their own branches into the release branch at a point or from a point up to which they consider them stable.

Comment: Bookmark is, in common, worse than tagging - devs must be aware of active|inactive bookmark (namely - auto-moving of active bookmark) and it isn't bulletproof-way. Tags with conventional names  ("stable-FEATURENAME") seems more adequate - devs can move existing tags only by hand by requst